# How to combine two value checks into one line in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in javascript:

```
var seasonDropdown = TVContainer.find('select.season').val()
if (seasonDropdown == "-1" || !seasonDropdown) {seasonDropdown = null}
```

Is there a way to combine these two into one line?

Comment: It looks like you are asking a JS question but you tagged it as python.

Comment: @NickEllis -- thanks, I've fixed it now.

Comment: You can do this in one line, but I would argue that makes it worse not better.  I would actually suggest you do this in 3 lines with the block below the if separated out.  Also you should ALWAYS use ===  for equality checks in JS.

Comment: @NickEllis could you please demonstrate what you mean by having it in three lines instead of 2 or 1? Do you just mean using the braces around the if?

Comment: @David542 typically, if you have braces, you want to separate the logic inside of the braces, on its own line;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
var seasonDropdown = (TVContainer.find('select.season').val() == "-1" || !TVContainer.find('select.season').val()) ? null : TVContainer.find('select.season').val();
```

But honestly, you should prefer readability over a solution like this.

---

if you want a bit cleaner look instead, you could use this:

```
var seasonDropdown = TVContainer.find('select.season').val();
if (seasonDropdown == "-1" || !seasonDropdown) seasonDropdown = null;
```